# Get remaining session time via ajax request without updating session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, jquery, popupwindow

I'm writing session reminder which pops up and counts down session time. The problem is with client side timer, it doesn't know about session update in other browser tab. So i need to check the time via ajax request in server side before showing reminder popup. 
By doing this remaining session time should not be updated.

I'm using IIS 8, .NET MVC 4

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your Controller as session-less, perhaps this can help you.

Try adding this attribute to your controller class:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class MyController
{
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Tried this, it makes session disabled for this request, but expiry time is still keep refreshed.